# Form is not getting displayed in codeigniter.

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to code igniter. I've created a form but it is not display properly.

When I put

**`<?php echo form_open('sms'); ?>`** instead of `<form action="">`tag
here in my form and controller, I can't understand why it is not displayed.

```
<?php echo form_open('sms'); ?>
            <p>
              <label><strong>Username</strong>
<input type="text" name="textfield" class="inputText" id="textfield" />
              </label>
          </p>
            <p>
              <label><strong>Password</strong>
  <input type="password" name="textfield2" class="inputText" id="textfield2" />
            </label>
            </p>

            <input type="submit" value="Authentification" name="auth" />
             <label>
             <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
              Remember me</label>            
          </form>
```

and my controller is

```
<?php

class  sms extends CI_Controller{
function school(){
    $this->load->view('school/index.php');

    if($this->input->post('auth',TRUE)){
     $this->load->view('school/dashboard.php');
    }
    else{
    $this->load->view('school/index.php');

    }
}
```

}

?>

Comment: What you can see in web source code?

Comment: <p class="error">This is when something is wrong!</p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your entire script for the most part, it looks like you need to load the helper first from the [CodeIgniter Form Helper Page](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html).

If you don't have this line, try adding it before the `form_open()` function:

```
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
```

While I have used CodeIgniter, it's been a while. Let me know if that changes the result.

**Edit:** Since you've chosen my answer I'll include this one, credits go out to [devo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926343/devo):

You could change `</form>` to: `<?php echo form_close(); ?>`. There are pros and cons for this method though, and without using arguments you might be better off sticking with `</form>`.

I'll explain further:

```
<div class="registration">
    <div class="form-box">
        <?php $this->load->helper( 'form' ); ?>
        <?php $end = '</div></div>'; ?>
        <?php echo form_open( 'register' ); ?>

        <!-- Form Inputs Here -->

        <?php echo form_close( $end ); ?>

        <!-- Echos '</form></div></div>' -->
```

So for closing the form without arguments, the `</form>` tag works best, both by performance and simplicity. The example used above is a rather simplistic view of what you can do with it, since what I wrote is not very efficient either.

However, this is still php we're talking about, so perhaps the craftier among us could put it to better use.

**End Edit**

Answer (score 1):

Have you loaded the form helper? You can use $this->load->helper('form'); in your controller action, her inside function school(). You can then use form helper in the view pages.

Comment: The CodeIgniter script uses the `form_open('sms')` to simply create an html form tag => `<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/sms" />`. Thus his MVC class `sms` will not load until the form is submit. The helper will not be loaded if it is in the controller action...

Answer (score 1):

Load form helper,

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

And use,

```
echo form_close()
```

Instead of,

```
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First in your Controller put in:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

And Change `</form>` to :

```
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```